# How to remove google accounts on android version Pie?

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-account

Programmatically, I want to remove the google account from the Account section. The below code is working properly on lower version devices but it is not working on Oreo and later version.
But I am getting this Exception

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10117 cannot remove
>   accounts of type: com.google

**Here is my code:**

```
final AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()));
        final Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        for (int index = 0; index < accounts.length; index++) {
            accountManager.removeAccount(accounts[index], null, null);
            // accountManager.removeAccountExplicitly(accounts[finalIndex]); Tried this line code as well.
          }
```

**I have given the below Permission as well.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

**After my research, I have added this code for Oreo and later version devices but still, I am not able to remove the Google Account.**

```
 public void requestGoogleAccountAccess() throws Exception {
        boolean googleAccountAccessGranted = GoogleAuthUtil.requestGoogleAccountsAccess(this);
        Log.i("", "googleAccountAccessGranted: " + googleAccountAccessGranted);
    }

    // exception handler after calling method above
    private void handleAuthResult(Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
            UserRecoverableAuthException authException = (UserRecoverableAuthException) e;
            startActivityForResult(authException.getIntent(), 12);
        } else {
            Log.e("", "Cannot request Google Account Access", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 12) {
            Log.i("", "Google Auth Permission Result");

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.w("", "User Cancelled Play Services Auth Request.");
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("", "User accepted Play Services Auth Request.");
                // call the following line again on a background thread. the call now returns a boolean instead of throwing an exception
                //  googleAccountAccessGranted = GoogleAuthUtil.requestGoogleAccountsAccess(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

**I have added Authenticator**

```
    public class Authenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
        // Simple constructor
        public Authenticator(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        // Editing properties is not supported
        @Override
        public Bundle editProperties(
                AccountAuthenticatorResponse r, String s) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        // Don't add additional accounts
        @Override
        public Bundle addAccount(
                AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
                String s,
                String s2,
                String[] strings,
                Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }

        // Ignore attempts to confirm credentials
        @Override
        public Bundle confirmCredentials(
                AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
                Account account,
                Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }

        // Getting an authentication token is not supported
        @Override
        public Bundle getAuthToken(
                AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
                Account account,
                String s,
                Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        // Getting a label for the auth token is not supported
        @Override
        public String getAuthTokenLabel(String s) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        // Updating user credentials is not supported
        @Override
        public Bundle updateCredentials(
                AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
                Account account,
                String s, Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        // Checking features for the account is not supported
        @Override
        public Bundle hasFeatures(
                AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
                Account account, String[] strings) throws NetworkErrorException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle getAccountRemovalAllowed(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return super.getAccountRemovalAllowed(response, account);
        }
    }

public class AuthenticatorService extends Service {

    // Instance field that stores the authenticator object
    private Authenticator mAuthenticator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Create a new authenticator object
        mAuthenticator = new Authenticator(this);
    }

    /*
     * When the system binds to this Service to make the RPC call
     * return the authenticator's IBinder.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mAuthenticator.getIBinder();
    }
}

// Authenticator.xml 
// My App Package Name is "com.accountdemo"
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="com.google"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/abc_vector_test" />

// Added these lines in Manifest 
        <service android:name=".AuthenticatorService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
```

**I have tested this code by using system signature platform keys but it's still not working. Please, someone, help me to resolve the issue. Thank you.**

Comment: i see a problem in your code

Comment: @user1241241 Could you please tell me?

Comment: the problem is removing google version in Android-P. Being able to do so will fix the issue

Comment: @user1241241 Could you please explain me what should I do? I have not understood it.

Comment: HI.Have you solve this?